# select time and add to getdate using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

i have a column TYPE_TOURNE type datetime that contain '1900-01-01 05:15:00.000'
i want to select just hour and minute and add to getdate().

example : now is **25/02/2013** then the result is  = `2013-02-25 05:15:00.000`

```
select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))+DATEPART(hh, TYPE_TOURNE) FROM TOURNE
```

but unfortunately the result is wrong

Comment: but you do get the desired format for output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add time from `TYPE_TOURNE` to `current date` and return as `datetime` then;

```
Select convert(datetime,
               convert(varchar, getdate(),112) + ' ' + 
               convert(varchar, TYPE_TOURNE, 114)
              ) newDate
From TOURNE
```

***OR*** if you need `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm` format then convert to `varchar with 121 format`

```
Select convert(varchar,
               convert(datetime,
                 convert(varchar, getdate(),112) + ' ' + 
                 convert(varchar, TYPE_TOURNE, 114)
              ), 121) newDate
From TOURNE
```

***OR*** if you need just `hour & minutes` from `TYPE_TOURNE` then

```
Select convert(varchar,
               convert(datetime,
                 convert(varchar, getdate(),112) + ' ' + 
                 left(convert(varchar, TYPE_TOURNE, 108),6) + '00'
              ), 121) newDate
From TOURNE
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), TYPE_TOURNE)
FROM TOURNE
```

or, return the TYPE_TOURNE and handle the formatting in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))+DATEADD(hh,0, TYPE_TOURNE) FROM TOURNE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TimeHolder DATETIME = '1900-01-01 05:15:00.000'

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, @TimeHolder), 
                   DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, @TimeHolder), 
                        DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME) + 
CAST(CONVERT(TIME, TYPE_TOURNE) AS DATETIME)
FROM   TOURNE
```